# Spark different result local run vs run on cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I experience some problems with a spark job I have. The job consists of some joins, repartition, followed by Map, groupbykey (with a string key) and eventually Aggregate using a commutative and associative agregator. I use Dataset API and kryo serialization in order to use generic objects in the dataset.

My problem is that I get different results when running on the cluster vs local run. Local runs result the same correct output every time but the cluster runs result different and incorrect output. Moreover, the output differs between different runs in the cluster.
I don't use any approximation operation, nor float values as keys. My guess is that it has something to do with the partitions or the execution over several executors though I have no further ideas. I'll be glad to hear any suggestions:)

Comment: Running spark on cluster my give different results from your local run propably because data is shuffled in the cluster, however it should always give the correct answer, it seems that your approach is indeterministic, so probably the problem either in your code, or data in the cluster is different or baddly consumed, can you share code/data that reproduce your problem ?